# How to merge 20+ csv files into 1 dataframe in R (adding new columns each time a new file is added)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 26 csv files with same number of rows and columns, which I wish to to merge into a single dataframe in R. A modified example is given below.

file1.csv

```
chrom   pos     PI
3       23435  0.1
3       35465  0.1
3       36487  0.2
3       37888  0.4
3       38516  0.1
```

file2.csv

```
chrom   pos     PI
3       23435  0.1
3       35465  0.1
3       36487  0.2
3       37888  0.4
3       38516  0.1
```

Desired output

```
chrom   pos     PI   chrom   pos     PI
3       23435  0.1   3       23435  0.1
3       35465  0.1   3       35465  0.1
3       36487  0.2   3       36487  0.2
3       37888  0.4   3       37888  0.4
3       38516  0.1   3       38516  0.1
```

I have written the following code which gives no error:

```
library(data.table)

file_list <- list.files('/home/aahm/SoftMaker/Documents/Aaisha/MPhil_PhD/2021/1.January/Results/csv_files/sitepi/ACKR2', pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

ldf <- lapply(file_list , read.csv)
df.final <- do.call("rbind", ldf)

View (df.final)
```

However, the outfile dataframe is in the following format:

```
chrom   pos     PI
3       23435  0.1
3       35465  0.1
3       36487  0.2
3       37888  0.4
3       38516  0.1
3       23435  0.1
3       35465  0.1
3       36487  0.2
3       37888  0.4
3       38516  0.1
```

What is wrong with my coding? And how should I do this? I would be very grateful for any help?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you need a different sorting...

```
df.final <- df.final[order(df.final$chrom, df.final$pos, df.final$PI),]


   chrom   pos  PI
1      3 23435 0.1
6      3 23435 0.1
2      3 35465 0.1
7      3 35465 0.1
3      3 36487 0.2
8      3 36487 0.2
4      3 37888 0.4
9      3 37888 0.4
5      3 38516 0.1
10     3 38516 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cbind` instead of `rbind`

```
> do.call(cbind, ldf)
  chrom   pos  PI chrom   pos  PI
1     3 23435 0.1     3 23435 0.1
2     3 35465 0.1     3 35465 0.1
3     3 36487 0.2     3 36487 0.2
4     3 37888 0.4     3 37888 0.4
5     3 38516 0.1     3 38516 0.1
```

---

**Update**

If you want to remove columns 1,2,4,5,...., you can try the code below

```
z <- do.call(cbind, ldf)
inds <- seq(1, length(z), by = 3)
z[-c(inds, inds + 1)]
```

**Data**

```
> dput(ldf)
list(structure(list(chrom = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), pos = c(23435L, 
35465L, 36487L, 37888L, 38516L), PI = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), structure(list(
    chrom = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), pos = c(23435L, 35465L, 36487L,
    37888L, 38516L), PI = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  
-5L)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is amazing. It works in a second! R just makes things so simple. Now, suppose I have to delete columns 1, 4, 5, 7, 8 ,10, 11, etc. till the end because they are repetitive. I can do this manually but is there a more ingenious way of doing it.

Comment: The column numbers to be deleted are y and z, where y = 1+3x (x = 1-25) z = 2+3x I also note that all x columns have same column name (chrom) and all y columns have same column name (pos). Deleting by column name would be easy but I need the first occurence of column y (pos). So maybe working by index would be better. I have tried various options but nothing seems to work properly.